# Genus of Fermat Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

The genus of a projective Fermat curve $x^d+y^d=z^d$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ can be computed using the formula $g={d-1\choose 2}$, where $d$ is the degree. Is the genus of the affine curve $x^d+y^d=1$ the same? If this were true, wouldn't the Euler characteristic $2-2g$ be the same?

Comment: What's your definition of the genus?

Comment: For curves, it would be the arithmetic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_genus

Comment: I think that the point of Marie's question is that for non-compact varieties, genus (arithmetic or otherwise) is not really a well-defined notion. Anyway, it's clear that the Euler characteristic of the affine part is _not_ the same: the Fermat curve has $d$ pointson the line at infinity, which you delete to go from the projective to the affine curve. How does that change $\chi$?

Comment: Ah, I get the point. So for the projective version the characteristic is $3d-d^2$, and we kill $d$ points in the affine version for characteristic $2d-d^2$..